# How do I create the environment for my genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, environment, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing a genetic algorithm in python about the optimal series of moves for a virtual organism that will get it the most randomly-placed food in a 2D-grid. It does not have intelligence; it just moves in a pattern ie circle or square. My code for creating the 2D array for the environment that the organisms reside in is this:

```
grid = ([])
for i in range(5):
    grid[i]=0
    for j in range(5):
        grid[i][j]=0
```

(board[4][5] means 4,5 in x, y; and the value of board[4][5] is 0 or 1, depending on 
whether or not the space is occupied. Right now the program is really just assigning
a zero-value to each space, indicating no individual is there)

It just says "list assignment index out of range." How can i fix this? By the way, does anyone know of a better way to create the 2D environment for the organisms?

Comment: Your problem is similar to the [Artificial Ant Problem](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/bloat_csrp-97-29/node2.html) in Genetic Programming. If you are interested, the problem have been implemented in Python with [DEAP](http://deap.googlecode.com). Here is the example [link](http://code.google.com/p/deap/source/browse/examples/gp_ant.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right now your array is only one element and you're indexing outside of the array.  Try this

```
grid = [[[] for x in xrange(5)] for y in xrange(5)]
```

in place of your grid.  This will now give you a 5 by 5 grid and now you can index grid[3][4].

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to require a lot of evaluations of your fitness function, so an efficient implementation might be very beneficial for you. Numpy offers multi-dimensional arrays out of the box.

```
numpy.zeros((5, 5))
```

it will give you a 5x5 array filled with zeros. Numpy offers also nice things like counting occurrences of a value, which will be way faster than a pure Python implementation.